# How to close previous screen in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, 4 screens are there. When I switch from one screen to another screen 2 or 3 times. At that time, I want to go to the 1st screen but previous screens are coming. How to close previous screens?

Comment: I edited the title to make more sense but I didn't touch the body. Please fix your question so that it is coherent.

Comment: Also, you have received a lot of good answers to your earlier questions. Please go back and tick those answers as accepted answers, before moving on to ask new questions. A lot of competent people will refrain from spending time on answering your questions, if you don't take the time to accept the answers you're given.

Comment: in my application from main screen to i swith to preference screen there i use apply button for background for main screen.then i gave esc the preference screen will closed.but i want it will go to main screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you mentioning activity as "screen"?
If yes, you can call finish() to close the current activity

Comment: He means to close the previous activity, but you're right that the answer is for him to call finish() right after he calls startActivity() so that the screen is closed before the new one even comes up.